# Code 14 when Dockerizing Web App Using node.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express, dockerfile

I am trying to Dockerize a web app I built using node.js and MongoDB, but when I run
docker-compose up
I am getting the following error:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

> Creating network "nodeapp1_default" with the default driver Creating
>   mongo ... done Creating app   ... done Attaching to mongo, app mongo
>   | 2019-02-05T15:02:34.925+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically
>   disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify
>   --sslDisabledProtocols 'none' mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:34.934+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017
>   dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=e4fb5b7aa837 mongo    |
>   2019-02-05T15:02:34.934+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version
>   v4.0.5 mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:34.935+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] git version: 3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412
>   mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:34.935+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016 mongo    |
>   2019-02-05T15:02:34.935+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator:
>   tcmalloc mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:34.936+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] modules: none mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:34.936+0000
>   I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment: mongo    |
>   2019-02-05T15:02:34.936+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod:
>   ubuntu1604 mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:34.937+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64 mongo    |
>   2019-02-05T15:02:34.937+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
>   target_arch: x86_64 mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:34.937+0000 I CONTROL 
>   [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true } } mongo    |
>   2019-02-05T15:02:34.941+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
>   wiredtiger_open config:
>   create,cache_size=256M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
>   mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:36.060+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten]
>   WiredTiger error (17) [1549378956:60130][1:0x7f0c375e0a40],
>   connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt:
>   handle-open: open: File exists Raw:
>   [1549378956:60130][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection: __posix_open_file,
>   715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists mongo    |
>   2019-02-05T15:02:36.066+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   error (26) [1549378956:66441][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection:
>   __posix_fs_rename, 253: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename: rename: Text file busy Raw:
>   [1549378956:66441][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection: __posix_fs_rename,
>   253: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename:
>   rename: Text file busy mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:36.077+0000 E
>   STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17)
>   [1549378956:77316][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection: __posix_open_file,
>   715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw:
>   [1549378956:77316][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection: __posix_open_file,
>   715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists mongo    |
>   2019-02-05T15:02:36.078+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   error (26) [1549378956:78533][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection:
>   __posix_fs_rename, 253: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename: rename: Text file busy Raw:
>   [1549378956:78533][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection: __posix_fs_rename,
>   253: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename:
>   rename: Text file busy mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:36.090+0000 E
>   STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17)
>   [1549378956:90882][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection: __posix_open_file,
>   715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw:
>   [1549378956:90882][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection: __posix_open_file,
>   715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists mongo    |
>   2019-02-05T15:02:36.092+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger
>   error (26) [1549378956:92202][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection:
>   __posix_fs_rename, 253: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename: rename: Text file busy Raw:
>   [1549378956:92202][1:0x7f0c375e0a40], connection: __posix_fs_rename,
>   253: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt to /data/db/WiredTiger.wt.1: file-rename:
>   rename: Text file busy mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:36.094+0000 W
>   STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any
>   compatibility version. mongo    | 2019-02-05T15:02:36.094+0000 F
>   STORAGE  [initandlisten] Reason: 26: Text file busy mongo    |
>   2019-02-05T15:02:36.094+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal
>   Assertion 28595 at
>   src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 638 mongo
>   | 2019-02-05T15:02:36.094+0000 F -        [initandlisten] mongo    |
>   mongo    | ***aborting after fassert() failure mongo    | mongo    |
>   mongo exited with code 14

Here is my Dockerfile:

> FROM node:8
>
> WORKDIR /usr/src/app
>
> COPY package*.json ./
>
> RUN npm install
>
> COPY . .
>
> EXPOSE 3000 CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

and my docker-compose.yml file:

> version: "2" services:   app:
>       container_name: app
>       restart: always
>       build: .
>       ports:
>         - "3000:3000"
>       links:
>         - mongo   mongo:
>       container_name: mongo
>       image: mongo
>       volumes:
>         - ./data:/data/db
>       ports:
>         - "27017:27017"

The problem seems to be coming from some file called WhiteTiger.wt. I have tried erasing this file from the data directory of my project directory but that did not work. Has anyone come across this problem before?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I am assuming you are running Docker on Windows, and if so, I experienced the same issue and found the answer in the below post:

[Windows Docker mongo container doesn't work with volume mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42892993/windows-docker-mongo-container-doesnt-work-with-volume-mount)

The problem is that the volume mount is specified as a host volume. I resolved my issue by changing my volume mount to be a named volume. If you need to use host, you might be able to use the `rsync` tool specified in the answer to the question I linked.

My docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:

  mongodb1:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - data1:/data/db
      - config1:/data/configdb
    ports:
      - 30001:27017
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
volumes:
  data1:
  config1:
```